# routes problems after devise gem update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I used Devise 3.0, everything was ok, but since i use Devise 3.2.4 i got lot of problem with my routes...

With Devise 3.0, this code worked :

```
devise_for :users,
:controllers => {  :registrations => "users/registrations",
  :passwords => "users/passwords",
  :sessions => 'users/sessions'}, 
  :skip => [:sessions] do
    get 'identification' => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'identification' => 'users/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get 'deconnexion' => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'inscription' => 'users/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    get 'mot-de-passe' => "users/passwords#new", :as => :new_password_user
    get 'mon-compte'   => "users/registrations#edit",   :as => :edit_user_registration 
  end
  devise_scope :user do
    get "users/pdf", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "pdf"
    get "users/download_pdf", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "download_pdf"
    get "informations-personnelles", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile0", :as => "users_edit_profile0"
    get "vous-et-votre-projet", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile1", :as => "users_edit_profile1"
    get "caracteristiques-du-bien", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile2", :as => "users_edit_profile2"
    get "details-du-bien", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile3", :as => "users_edit_profile3"
    get "quartier", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile4", :as => "users_edit_profile4"
    get "lieu", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile5", :as => "users_edit_profile5"
    get "budget", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile6", :as => "users_edit_profile6"
    get "coup-de-coeur", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "edit_profile7", :as => "users_edit_profile7"
    put "users/update_avatar", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_avatar"    
    put "users/update_profile0", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile0"    
    put "users/update_profile1", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile1"
    put "users/update_profile2", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile2"
    put "users/update_profile3", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile3"
    put "users/update_profile4", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile4"
    put "users/update_profile5", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile5"
    put "users/update_profile6", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile6"
    put "users/update_profile7", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "update_profile7"

    get "users/heating", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "heating", :as => :heating
    get "users/water_heater", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => "water_heater", :as => :water_heater
  end
end
```

Since i use Devise 3.2.4 i got some problems like :

```
undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_path'
```

Or

```
undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path'
```

I worked few hours on that problem but i cant find the good solution...

The result of `rake routes` is :

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
         process_webhook POST   /webhooks/process(.:format)                 webhooks#handle
          verify_webhook GET    /webhooks/process(.:format)                 webhooks#verify
          reset_webhooks DELETE /webhooks/reset(.:format)                   webhooks#destroy_all
                webhooks GET    /webhooks(.:format)                         webhooks#index
                         POST   /webhooks(.:format)                         webhooks#create
             invitations GET    /invitations(.:format)                      invitations#index
                         POST   /invitations(.:format)                      invitations#create
          new_invitation GET    /invitations/new(.:format)                  invitations#new
         edit_invitation GET    /invitations/:id/edit(.:format)             invitations#edit
              invitation GET    /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#show
                         PATCH  /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#update
                         PUT    /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#update
                         DELETE /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#destroy


   authenticated_user_root GET    /                                           messages#index
  authenticated_realtor_root GET    /                                           pro/users#index
        unauthenticated_root GET    /                                           static_pages#home
                new_customer GET    /customer/new(.:format)                     customer#new
               edit_customer GET    /customer/:id/edit(.:format)                customer#edit
       edit_credit_card_info GET    /credit_card_info/:id/edit(.:format)        credit_card_info#edit
            confirm_customer GET    /customer/confirm(.:format)                 customer#confirm
    confirm_credit_card_info GET    /credit_card_info/confirm(.:format)         credit_card_info#confirm
             new_transaction GET    /transactions/:product_id/new(.:format)     transactions#new
         confirm_transaction GET    /transactions/confirm/:product_id(.:format) transactions#confirm
                update_areas GET    /update_areas(.:format)                     areas#update_areas
                 about_users GET    /a-propos(.:format)                         static_pages#about
              about_realtors GET    /pro/a-propos(.:format)                     static_pages#about_realtors
          how_it_works_users GET    /comment-ca-marche(.:format)                static_pages#how_it_works
               home_realtors GET    /pro(.:format)                              static_pages#home_realtors
       how_it_works_realtors GET    /pro/comment-ca-marche(.:format)            static_pages#how_it_works_realtors
            pricing_realtors GET    /pro/abonnements(.:format)                  static_pages#pricing
                 press_users GET    /espace-presse(.:format)                    static_pages#press
              press_realtors GET    /pro/espace-presse(.:format)                static_pages#press_realtors
                 terms_users GET    /conditions-utilisation(.:format)           static_pages#terms
              terms_realtors GET    /pro/conditions-utilisation(.:format)       static_pages#terms_realtors
                legals_users GET    /mentions-legales(.:format)                 static_pages#legals
             legals_realtors GET    /pro/mentions-legales(.:format)             static_pages#legals_realtors
           static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)                static_pages#home
    static_pages_user_mailer GET    /static_pages/user_mailer(.:format)         static_pages#user_mailer
      pro_users_show_partial GET    /pro/users/show_partial(.:format)           pro/users#show_partial
     pro_users_show_complete GET    /pro/users/show_complete(.:format)          pro/users#show_complete
            pro_search_users GET    /pro/users/search_users(.:format)           pro/users#search_users
           load_user_profile GET    /pro/users/load_user_profile/:id(.:format)  pro/users#load_user_profile
                     new_map GET    /pro/users/new_map(.:format)                pro/users#new_map
                 new_contact GET    /pro/users/new_contact/:id(.:format)        pro/messages#new_contact
               realtors_show GET    /realtors/show(.:format)                    realtors#show
                        root GET    /                                           static_pages#home
           list_cities_areas GET    /areas/list_cities(.:format)                areas#list_cities
            list_depts_areas GET    /areas/list_depts(.:format)                 areas#list_depts
                  city_areas GET    /areas/city(.:format)                       areas#city
                  dept_areas GET    /areas/dept(.:format)                       areas#dept
                             GET    /areas/kml/:hash(.:format)                  areas#kml
                       areas GET    /areas(.:format)                            areas#index
                             POST   /areas(.:format)                            areas#create
                    new_area GET    /areas/new(.:format)                        areas#new
                   edit_area GET    /areas/:id/edit(.:format)                   areas#edit
                        area GET    /areas/:id(.:format)                        areas#show
                             PATCH  /areas/:id(.:format)                        areas#update
                             PUT    /areas/:id(.:format)                        areas#update
                             DELETE /areas/:id(.:format)                        areas#destroy
      list_children_children GET    /children/list_children(.:format)           children#list_children
          add_child_children GET    /children/add_child(.:format)               children#add_child
                    children GET    /children(.:format)                         children#index
                             POST   /children(.:format)                         children#create
                   new_child GET    /children/new(.:format)                     children#new
                  edit_child GET    /children/:id/edit(.:format)                children#edit
                       child GET    /children/:id(.:format)                     children#show
                             PATCH  /children/:id(.:format)                     children#update
                             PUT    /children/:id(.:format)                     children#update
                             DELETE /children/:id(.:format)                     children#destroy
                    messages GET    /messages(.:format)                         messages#index
                             POST   /messages(.:format)                         messages#create
                 new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)                     messages#new
                edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)                messages#edit
                     message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)                     messages#show
                             PATCH  /messages/:id(.:format)                     messages#update
                             PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)                     messages#update
                             DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)                     messages#destroy
             load_discussion GET    /messages/load_discussion/:id(.:format)     messages#load_discussion
                  faye_alive GET    /messages/faye_alive/:id(.:format)          messages#faye_alive
                             GET    /invitations(.:format)                      invitations#index
                             POST   /invitations(.:format)                      invitations#create
                             GET    /invitations/new(.:format)                  invitations#new
                             GET    /invitations/:id/edit(.:format)             invitations#edit
                             GET    /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#show
                             PATCH  /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#update
                             PUT    /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#update
                             DELETE /invitations/:id(.:format)                  invitations#destroy
             load_invitation GET    /invitations/load_invitation/:id(.:format)  invitations#load_invitation
                pro_messages GET    /pro/messages(.:format)                     pro/messages#index
                             POST   /pro/messages(.:format)                     pro/messages#create
             new_pro_message GET    /pro/messages/new(.:format)                 pro/messages#new
            edit_pro_message GET    /pro/messages/:id/edit(.:format)            pro/messages#edit
                 pro_message GET    /pro/messages/:id(.:format)                 pro/messages#show
                             PATCH  /pro/messages/:id(.:format)                 pro/messages#update
                             PUT    /pro/messages/:id(.:format)                 pro/messages#update
                             DELETE /pro/messages/:id(.:format)                 pro/messages#destroy
         pro_discussion_user GET    /pro/discussion/:id(.:format)               pro/messages#index
         pro_load_discussion GET    /pro/messages/load_discussion/:id(.:format) pro/messages#load_discussion
                   pro_users GET    /pro/users(.:format)                        pro/users#index
                             POST   /pro/users(.:format)                        pro/users#create
                new_pro_user GET    /pro/users/new(.:format)                    pro/users#new
               edit_pro_user GET    /pro/users/:id/edit(.:format)               pro/users#edit
                    pro_user GET    /pro/users/:id(.:format)                    pro/users#show
                             PATCH  /pro/users/:id(.:format)                    pro/users#update
                             PUT    /pro/users/:id(.:format)                    pro/users#update
                             DELETE /pro/users/:id(.:format)                    pro/users#destroy
              pro_list_users GET    /pro/acheteurs(.:format)                    pro/users#index
               pro_this_user GET    /pro/acheteur/:id(.:format)                 pro/users#show
                         pro GET    /pro/users/download_pdf/:id(.:format)       pro/users#download_pdf
            realtor_password POST   /realtors/password(.:format)                realtors/passwords#create
        new_realtor_password GET    /realtors/password/new(.:format)            realtors/passwords#new
       edit_realtor_password GET    /realtors/password/edit(.:format)           realtors/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /realtors/password(.:format)                realtors/passwords#update
                             PUT    /realtors/password(.:format)                realtors/passwords#update
 cancel_realtor_registration GET    /realtors/cancel(.:format)                  realtors/registrations#cancel
        realtor_registration POST   /realtors(.:format)                         realtors/registrations#create
    new_realtor_registration GET    /realtors/sign_up(.:format)                 realtors/registrations#new
   edit_realtor_registration GET    /realtors/edit(.:format)                    realtors/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /realtors(.:format)                         realtors/registrations#update
                             PUT    /realtors(.:format)                         realtors/registrations#update
                             DELETE /realtors(.:format)                         realtors/registrations#destroy
   realtors_credit_card_info GET    /realtors/credit_card_info(.:format)        realtors/registrations#credit_card_info
realtors_cancel_subscription GET    /realtors/cancel_subscription(.:format)     realtors/registrations#cancel_subscription
      realtors_edit_profile0 GET    /pro/informations-personnelles(.:format)    realtors/registrations#edit_profile0
      realtors_edit_profile1 GET    /pro/zone-activite(.:format)                realtors/registrations#edit_profile1
       realtors_edit_profile GET    /realtors/edit_profile(.:format)            realtors/registrations#edit_profile
    realtors_update_profile1 PUT    /realtors/update_profile1(.:format)         realtors/registrations#update_profile1
    realtors_update_profile0 PUT    /realtors/update_profile0(.:format)         realtors/registrations#update_profile0
      realtors_update_avatar PUT    /realtors/update_avatar(.:format)           realtors/registrations#update_avatar
        realtors_update_logo PUT    /realtors/update_logo(.:format)             realtors/registrations#update_logo
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   users/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               users/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              users/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   users/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   users/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     users/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    users/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       users/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                             PUT    /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#update
                             DELETE /users(.:format)                            users/registrations#destroy
                   users_pdf GET    /users/pdf(.:format)                        users/registrations#pdf
          users_download_pdf GET    /users/download_pdf(.:format)               users/registrations#download_pdf
         users_edit_profile0 GET    /informations-personnelles(.:format)        users/registrations#edit_profile0
         users_edit_profile1 GET    /vous-et-votre-projet(.:format)             users/registrations#edit_profile1
         users_edit_profile2 GET    /caracteristiques-du-bien(.:format)         users/registrations#edit_profile2
         users_edit_profile3 GET    /details-du-bien(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit_profile3
         users_edit_profile4 GET    /quartier(.:format)                         users/registrations#edit_profile4
         users_edit_profile5 GET    /lieu(.:format)                             users/registrations#edit_profile5
         users_edit_profile6 GET    /budget(.:format)                           users/registrations#edit_profile6
         users_edit_profile7 GET    /coup-de-coeur(.:format)                    users/registrations#edit_profile7
         users_update_avatar PUT    /users/update_avatar(.:format)              users/registrations#update_avatar
       users_update_profile0 PUT    /users/update_profile0(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile0
       users_update_profile1 PUT    /users/update_profile1(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile1
       users_update_profile2 PUT    /users/update_profile2(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile2
       users_update_profile3 PUT    /users/update_profile3(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile3
       users_update_profile4 PUT    /users/update_profile4(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile4
       users_update_profile5 PUT    /users/update_profile5(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile5
       users_update_profile6 PUT    /users/update_profile6(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile6
       users_update_profile7 PUT    /users/update_profile7(.:format)            users/registrations#update_profile7
           users_edit_delete GET    /users/edit_delete(.:format)                users/registrations#delete
                     heating GET    /users/heating(.:format)                    users/registrations#heating
                water_heater GET    /users/water_heater(.:format)               users/registrations#water_heater
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: `destroy_user_session_url` also not working?

Comment: @zishe : No, i got the same error `with destroy_user_session_url`...

Do you want the result of `rake routes` ?

Comment: @zishe, no... that url is not in the routes :( i post my routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the block to `devise_for` is deprecated in newer versions of `Devise`. This is why the routes that you passed to `devise_for` in a block are totally ignored. You can notice this in the `rake routes` result as well, those routes are nowhere to be seen.
And as the routes itself are not existing, you get the error when you access `destroy_user_session_path` or `new_user_session_path`.

To resolve this, you need to add those routes in `devise_scope` instead:

```
## You need to skip `:registrations` and `:passwords` routes too because you are resetting them as well
devise_for :users,
:controllers => {  :registrations => "users/registrations",
  :passwords => "users/passwords",
  :sessions => 'users/sessions'}, 
  :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

devise_scope :user do
  get 'identification' => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'identification' => 'users/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  get 'deconnexion' => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  get 'inscription' => 'users/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  get 'mot-de-passe' => "users/passwords#new", :as => :new_password_user
  get 'mon-compte'   => "users/registrations#edit",   :as => :edit_user_registration 
  ## Rest of the routes      
end
```

Checkout the [Github Devise Issue: devise_for block deprecation warning confuses](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1615) for your reference.

Comment: I tried that but i got that message : `ArgumentError (Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_registration' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with 'resources' as explained here: .....`

Comment: Ohh..I missed that. You are resetting registration and password routes as well. So you need to skip those too in `devise_for`. Read my updated answer.

Comment: So, i tried to add "registrations" in `:skip => [:sessions, :registrations].
With that, it's ok for `new_user_registration` but that create an error `undefined method 'user_registration_path'`

Comment: That's because you forgot to create a route for that. As you are skipping `registrations`, no readymade routes would be created for you. You would have to add all the required routes in `devise_scope`

Comment: so i've to create all the "classic" Devise routes ? right ? :)

Comment: Yes.. that's the way it is.:)